# Do Arcane Ward's starting hit points include the INT modifier once or twice?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard

An abjuration wizard's *Arcane Ward* states:

> [...] The ward has hit points equal to twice your wizard level + your Intelligence modifier.

So how many hit points is this supposed to be?

\$ (2 \times WizardLevel) + INT_{mod}\$

or

\$2 \times (WizardLevel + INT_{mod})\$ ?

I feel like the phrasing *hints* toward the first calculation, but it's still somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is 
\$ (2 \times WizardLevel) + INT_{mod}\$.

Fortunately, Jeremy Crawford has clarified this [in this Sage Advice tweet](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/765984419945390080):

> Arcane Ward—its hit point maximum equals your Intelligence modifier plus twice your wizard level.

It might also be worth it to note that this interpretation follows the more natural mathematical [Order of Operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). (credit to [Gandalfmeansme](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30218/gandalfmeansme) for noticing this)

Comment: One also notes that since the two quantities have different 'units' (levels _vs_ modifiers), it would be strange to combine their numbers before doubling unless explicitly directed to do so.

Answer (score -1):

IntMod+(2xWizLvl)

Is the rules-as-written answer, If your DM prefers to strictly follow the book I would go with that.

However, just adding the Intelligence bonus becomes negligible quickly, so it's reasonable to houserule that it adds double the Intellegence bonus instead. With with this change and a high intelligence at level 2—4 the difference is noticeable, after some levels it becomes just a nice buff.

Obviously check with the table first, but if you use homebrew or 3rd party rules I think most DMs would give without problem this bonus to a player who asked for it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a language or translation issue. "political?" answer? Do you mean "Correct" according to RAW (Rules As Written?) "Rules I'll Take for granted for a nice master?" I'm trying but can't parse this at all.

I think you meant at the end the Mod bonus is potentially big at the lower levels and becomes proportionally less important at higher levels. Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: Corrected the original comment sorry for that, with political I meant Rules As Written, some groups can be problematic if the master give an advantage to someone but it's quite rare when they already use some houserules.

The intelligence bonus normally is barely noticeable after a couple of levels, if you follow my suggestion and you have an optimized intelligence score it's quite a powerful increase for the first levels: at level 2 with 16 intelligence it changes from 7 to 10, at level 20 with 20 in intelligence it changes from 45 hp to 50 hp