# What’s the right calculation for the Homunculus’s hit points for the 2019 UA Alchemist Artificer?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, hit-points, alchemist, artificer

In the [2019 version of the Unearthed Arcana Alchemist Artificer](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA-Artificer-2019.pdf), the Homunculus's hit points are given as:

> Hit Points equal to five times your level in this class + your Intelligence modifier

Is this calculated as
\$(5\times level) + {Int Mod}\$
or
\$5\times (level + {int mod})\$?

Comment: Hey there! Welcome to the site! Be sure to take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour). Great first question!

Comment: Just because the wording of the features is similar and the answer likely the same doesn't mean the question is a duplicate. The questions are distinct

Answer (score 12):

## (5 × level) + INT mod

Because no parentheses or other mathematical indicators are given in the **Hit Points** section of the Homunculus stat block,

> Hit Points equal to five times your level in this class + your Intelligence modifier

directly translates to "HP = 5 × [your level in this class] + [your Intelligence modifier]", which in turn means "HP = (5 × [your level in this class]) + [your Intelligence modifier]", because of the [order of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations).

Rubiksmoose also notes that Jeremy Crawford has given guidance on similar subjects. One of his tweets is [here](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/765984419945390080), addressing the Arcane Ward feature for Abjuration Wizards:

> [...] The ward has hit points equal to twice your wizard level + your Intelligence modifier.

Comment: There are also several other rulings that were made and clarified by JC that (IIRC) came to this same conclusion but my search-fu has thus far failed to turn them up. There have been at least 2 Q&As here that I can recall. If you can find them it would be good support for this ruling possibly.

Comment: Here is one: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/124367/do-arcane-wards-starting-hit-points-include-the-int-modifier-once-or-twice